# I want to write an sql query having count function on one column also having where clause with like

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

In a program i have written following sql query  but it is giving error and not showing the result that i want it to display

```
s = "Select count(a.FileNo)'members',a.FileNo,a.ApplicantName from Easy_Loan_Agreement a where a.FileNo like ('" + textBox1.Text + "%" + "')group by'" + textBox1.Text + "'";
```

error is;

> each group by expression must contain atleast one column that is not
>   an outer reference

Answer (score 1):

First of all use parametrized queries for security reasons.

Second you do not need to pass values to `group by` as it is clear by which columns you have to group by.

Also you have to group by columns that are not used in aggregation not by column you are counting by and so you can't count `FileNo` and group by it as that makes not sense, if you want to find how many `FileNo - ApplicantName` count there is count by other column.

Query should look like this:

```
select count(*) as 'members', a.FileNo, a.ApplicantName 
from Easy_Loan_Agreement a
where a.FileNo like (@search + '%')
group by a.Id, a.ApplicantName
```

and in your code:

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con)) 
{
      con.Open();
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", textBox1.Text);

      var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Comment: I would use `like (@search)` and set parameter as `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", textBox1.Text+ '%');` , 1+ for other improvements you suggested

Answer (score -1):

```
s = "Select count(a.FileNo)'members',a.FileNo,a.ApplicantName from Easy_Loan_Agreement a

where a.FileNo like ('" + textBox1.Text + "%" + "') group by a.FileNo";
```

Comment: please explain how your answer solve the problem? you forgot `ApplicantName` column in group by  and also your solution is open for sql injection attacks.